# Cannot display a SocketAddr returned by peer_addr()

Tags: rust

I'm trying to print the address returned by peer_addr() of a TcpStream but Rust gives the error:

> error: the trait `core::fmt::Display` is not implemented for the type `core::result::Result<std::net::addr::SocketAddr, std::io::error::Error>` [E0277]
>   src/main.rs:29     format!("New client {}", stream.peer_addr());

According to the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html) Display is implemented.

Code is as follows:

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;

fn main()
{
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:80").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                thread::spawn(move|| {
                    // connection succeeded
                    handle_client(stream)
                });
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Accept err {}", e);
            }
        }
    }

    // close the socket server
    drop(listener);
}

fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    println!("New client {}", stream.peer_addr());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the compiler error carefully you can see, that your variable is of the type `core::result::Result<std::net::addr::SocketAddr, std::io::error::Error>`. You need to get the `SocketAddr` out of there. Sadly, the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.peer_addr) does not specify when an `Err` value is returned. The easiest solution:

```
println!("New client {}", stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
```

Of course `unwrap()` is evil and you should do proper error handling here!